# Can't merge undo disks on Virtual Server 2005

Tags: virtual-server

Error message: "Virtual Server was unable to commit the changes made during the current session of "". A likely cause of this problem is the parent virtual hard disk cannot be opened for read/write or it might be in use or the user has no read/write/modify permissions. The data in the undo disk is retained."

I can start up that virtual machine, do work on it, it gets saved, but when I try to overwrite the undo disk, I get this message. **How can I check if I have the required permission to overwrite the undo disk?** Of course I turned off the virtual machine first, and tried to initiate a "Merge Undo Disks" operation that way, so I don't think that the virtual hard disk is locked.

UPDATE: the virtual hard disk file could be renamed, so there is nothing locking that file.

Answer (score 1):

Once saw this as well.

Here is a solution thanks to [Kurt Guenther](http://home.infusionblogs.com/kguenther/archive/2006/06/20/virtual-server-undo-disks-i-am-never-going-to-use-you-again-cant-merge-disks-parent-disk-is-a-part-of-a-saved-state.aspx).

1. Rename the undo disks to *.vhd.  This turns them into a virtual drive in the eyes of Virtual Server.
2. Click on the Inspect option in the Virtual Disk section of Virtual Server.  There should be an option to then merge the disk.
3. Select a new disk to merge into.  If you try merging into the original parent, Virtual Server will just give you the above error again.
4. Take your newly merged virtual disk and replace it in the virtual machine (i.e. replace the parent that was couldn't be merged to before).

Make sure you have enough diskspace left before you start this procedure.